# Django having trouble linking a UserProfile to User

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So im wanting to extend the django auth.User model to add extra fields. Ive read a few articles here and there, and am almost there.

Im just trying to make the signup form at the moment. So a new user can sign up. I can get the new User created but when I come to save the UserProfile object to the database it fails citing

```
Cannot assign "u'clare'": "Customer.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

where "clare" is the username ive put in. This user is created in Auth.User, but the UserProfile, in this case called Customer is not created. So I think im doing something wrong when creating the object and using the foreign key to do so. Anyway below are the relevant files.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from RadioBusiSite.music.models import PlayList
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class Location(models.Model):
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Size = models.IntegerField('Size of Premises')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Address

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    Company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ContactPerson = models.CharField('Contact Person', max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ABN = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    Playlist = models.ManyToManyField(PlayList)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Company
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from RadioBusiSite.customer.models import Customer
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

class CustomerForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='User Name')
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=' Check Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    Company = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    ContactPerson = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    ABN = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    #Location = forms.ForeignKey(Location)
    #Playlist = forms.ManyToManyField(PlayList)

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You must type the same password each time")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def clean_user(self):
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['user'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['user']
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user is already in use. Please Choose another one.")

    def save(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username = self.cleaned_data['user'],
                                            email = self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                            password = self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        new_customer = Customer.objects.create(user=self.cleaned_data['user'],
                                               company = self.cleaned_data['Company'],
                                               ContactPerson = self.cleaned_data['ContactPerson'],
                                               email = self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                               ABN = self.cleaned_data['ABN'])
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from RadioBusiSite.customer.models import Customer,Location
from RadioBusiSite.customer.forms import CustomerForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def addCustomer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #user = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()

    return render_to_response('addCustomer.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

And ive enabled the AUTH think like so

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'customer.Customer'

the file above are all in a folder called "customer"

Any help would be great.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def save(self):
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username = self.cleaned_data['user'],
                        email = self.cleaned_data['email'],
                        password = self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    new_customer = Customer.objects.create(user=**new_user**,
                           company = self.cleaned_data['Company'],
                           ContactPerson = self.cleaned_data['ContactPerson'],
                           email = self.cleaned_data['email'],
                           ABN = self.cleaned_data['ABN'])
```

Notice the change `**within stars**` above.  :)

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. Just pass the object created above into the other object. Genius!